# Is there a case where self.location != document.location?

Tags: javascript, dom

In JavaScript, is there a case where `self.location != document.location`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `window.self` property is a reference back to `window`, and `window.location` is the same object as `document.location`.

So, the only possibility to get that expression to be true, is to redefine either `self` or `document`.

Comment: and window is a property of the global object which is a reference back to the global object. The DOM is full of mysteries... :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on the scope. As far as I know it is possible to (re)define `self` in an object or even in the global scope, so in that case `self.location` would point to nothing. Like this:

```
//[in global scope]
var self = new SomeObject;
alert(self.loction); //undefined

//in a constructor
function SomeObject(){
  var self = this;
  alert(self.location); //undefined
}
```

Bottom line seems: do not blindly depend on the availability of `self` as alias for `document`

Answer (score 0):

document.location is a **string**, not an object, 
and it has been replaced by document.URL.

An url that is redirected by the server does not have to update the window.location,
but the document.URL always shows the path to the current document.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't post a comment, apparently `self.location` == `document.location` == `window.location` in a frame. Only `top.location` is different. (Tested in Firefox 3.6.6 and Internet Explorer 8)